# select an object in blender using python command

Tags: python, objects, edit-mode, scene, object-mode

I'm having problem in working with various objects in blender. I'm writing a code to change the vertices of a object; but, it does not work when there are several objects at the scene, the problem is that I'm not getting change to the edit mode because of the "type" of the selection that I'm doing. When I select one object it do not necessary became the "master" object and so commands like
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
doesn't work.

I will put a photo to try to explain what a want to say with 'master' object [image]

even when I select the "Circle" and deselect the "Empty" object, the last one remains marked. If someone can help, I appreciate.

Comment: If you are using `bpy ops` commands, be aware that they work on the _active_ object, not the selected one(s).  The _active_ object is usually the last object selected.

Comment: I just tested this and it seems bpy.ops applies to the selected objects regardless of their active state. So you need to set the selection state of the objects using `obj.select_set(False)` (Blender 3.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the objects selection state. bpy.ops (in my brief testing) applies to whatever objects are selected, regardless of whether they are active...

Eg. Add an empty into a default scene with a cube...

````py
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-5, 0, 1))
obj.select_set(False)
#bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = None

emObj = bpy.data.objects['Empty']
#bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = emObj
emObj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(3, 0, -1))
```
````